# How to access a method's attribute

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

Is it possible to access a method's attribute directly? I tried this and it fails:

```
class Test1:
    def show_text(self):
        self.my_text = 'hello'
```

Which results in:

```
>>> t = Test1()
>>> t.my_text
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Test1 instance has no attribute 'my_text'
```

I found that using this made it work:

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_text = 'hello'
```

But I'm wondering if it's still possible to access attributes of methods directly? Or am I doing something Very Bad?

Comment: That's not a method attribute. It's just an instance attribute set in a method other than `__init__`. A *real* method attribute would look like `Test1.show_text.method_label`.

Comment: Thank you for all the excellent answers. They've all helped me understand the gizzards better :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instance variables are created once the object has been instantiated and only after they have been assigned to.

```
class Example(object):
      def doSomething(self):
          self.othervariable = 'instance variable'

>> foo = Example()
>> foo.othervariable
AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'othervariable'
```

Since `othervariable` is assigned inside `doSomething` - and we haven't called it yet -, it does not exist.

Once we call it, though:

```
>> foo.doSomething()
>> foo.othervariable
'instance variable'
```

---

`__init__` is a special method that automatically gets invoked whenever class instantiation happens. Which is why when you assign your variable in there, it is accessible right after you create a new instance.

```
class Example(object):

      def __init__(self):
          self.othervariable = 'instance variable'

>> foo = Example()
>> foo.othervariable
'instance variable'
```

Answer (score 2):

`my_text` attribute doesn't exist until you don't call `show_text`:

```
>>> class Test1:
...         def show_text(self):
...                 self.my_text = 'hello'
...         
>>> t  = Test1()
>>> t.show_text()
>>> t.my_text
'hello'
```

If you want your attributes to be created during instance creation then place them in `__init__` method.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example didn't work: since you never use `show_text()` method, your object will never have attribute `my_text` (that will be "added" to your object only when you invoke that method).

Second example is good, because `__init__` method is executed as soon as your object is instantiated.

Moreover, is a good practice to access object attribute through getter method on object itself so the best way you can modify your code is

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.my_text = value
    def show_text(self):
        return self.my_text
```

and then use in that way

```
t = Test1('hello')
t.show_text()
```

At last, will be also good to have a method like this

```
def set_text(self,new_text):
    self.my_text = new_text
```